# killing a job running in the background

Tags: shell-script, kill, process-management

I have started running a long job by creating a script that executes several commands on 20 or so datasets sequentially. I began in the xterm window with

```
$ script.scr
```

then typed

```
<ctrl-Z>
```

then called

```
$ bg
```

and then exited the window. I have now returned and started another xterm window and decided to kill the job, but when I identify the PID with top and then

```
$ kill PID
```

the current process PID is killed but the job then starts the next command line of the script.

I could manually then kill again the new PID created but since there are 20 or more similar command lines in the script this becomes tedious. Is there a short (efficient) way of killing the whole job?

$ killall PID     just kills the current process then a new one starts just the

same as using kill.

$ killall script.scr does not have any effect

Comment: Does killing the job lead to the same results? `kill %jobnumber`

Comment: Can you post the scrip.scr script here...if possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command `killall script.scr`